# BigQuery INNER JOIN with TIMESTAMP and DATE types

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query two different tables in Google BigQuery. 
In my first table (smgradi) i have two fields:

- data -> TIMESTAMP
- ConsumoKwh -> INTEGER

In my second table (meteodata) i have other two fields:

- DATA -> DATE
- TMEDIA___C -> INTEGER

I want to merge those tables with tables, but I have to convert the first TIMESTAMP column into a DATE column.

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT smgradi.data, smgradi.ConsumoKwh, meteodata.TMEDIA___C
FROM energy_unitus.smgradi AS smgradi
INNER JOIN energy_unitus.meteodata AS meteodata
  ON DATE(smgradi.data) = meteodata.DATA
```

But it gives the following error:

> Query Failed
>   Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. .

I also tried to compare the columns without "DATE", but it obviously return a blank table.
Can you help me with this?
Thank you,
Paolo

Answer (score 0):

This error is a limitation of Legacy SQL dialect. To get around it in Legacy SQL, you would need to do type transformation in subquery:

```
SELECT smgradi.data, smgradi.ConsumoKwh, meteodata.TMEDIA___C
FROM (SELECT DATE(data) data, ConsumoKwh FROM energy_unitus.smgradi) AS smgradi
INNER JOIN energy_unitus.meteodata AS meteodata
  ON data = meteodata.DATA
```

But also, please consider using Standard SQL, which doesn't have such limitation.